# change the scrollbar style of iframe only

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

I want to change the style of scrollbars of iframe only, not the style of scrollbars of window. I've seen the style of webkit and body css, but these change the style of window scrollbars. Is there any possible way to have different scrollbar in iframe than the parent window.

Comment: Just define the styles inside the iframed document, it's a document of its own and anything defined inside will not affect the outside document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Pekka commented is accurate. However, some browsers actually "creates" the scrollbars in the page where you have the iframe in, so there you need to use an ID for the iframe, and set the styles like:

```
iframe#id_name { style information }
```

However, most browsers let the scrollbars be created by the page you are iframing, in which case you need to specify the CSS styles for them within that page, like Pekka said.

It's all about which page is responsible for "making" the scrollbars when they are needed.

Hopefully that helps.